# Facebook Realtime Updates - getting empty data

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra

I have configured my application to do realtime updates.

[image]

The verification has been done and I get an update when the (text) user uploads a photo. This is good. But the POST data is completely empty, no data.

```
post "/fb_realtime_updates" do
  puts params[:object]
end
```

That will print "{}". Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Not sure what language (Ruby?) or HTTP server you're using.  I suggest you log the POST request header & body, so that you can work out whether the problem lies in the FB Subscription or your parsing of the body.  Do you expect `params` to contain the request body parsed as JSON?  Because you should be getting a JSON body (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Comment: @RichardBarnett : I'm using Sinatra (Ruby). The POST data should be part of the params collection, so in the scenario above there was no POST data. If I get a chance later I'll fire up wireshark and check the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object suggests you should be using

```
post "/fb_realtime_updates" do
  request.body.rewind  # in case someone already read it
  data = JSON.parse request.body.read
  puts data['object']
end
```

I don't have a Ruby/Sinatra environment to test this.